# Flex 4: how to have a drop down list of Checkboxes

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, checkbox, drop-down-menu, flex4

How would I get a drop downlist to populate with check boxes.
I am porting a c# project to flex, and I would like to imitate the functionality of their checkbox drop list.

Anyone got any idea how I would go about this.

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you do this by creating a custom ItemRenderer and assigning it to your DropDownList.  Here's an example of creating/applying a custom ItemRenderer in a DropDownList:

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2010/05/13/setting-the-text-roll-over-color-on-a-spark-dropdownlist-control-in-flex-4/

Hope that helps.

Comment: I just specified mx.controls.checkbox as the renderer that worked great thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you could extend the popup-button and add custom item renderer for the items in the dropdown.

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/2/langref/mx/controls/PopUpButton.html

Comment: Do you by any chance have an example of the code required to do this.

And to return the selected items?

Comment: The above is specific to the halo PopUpButton.  The original question refers to the spark DropDownList component.  I would recommend looking at the docs for the latter instead.

Comment: @Wade yes! you are right. in spark you need DropDownList.   @Craig Please check the itemRenderer examples for lists and see how stuff is done in there. I am sorry I do not have an example of it

Comment: Hi what I did in the end was I simply used a combolist with itemrendere set to the checkbox control this worked :)

Comment: There is an addendum to this problem, I cant actually click the check boxes.. the moment one does the dropdownlist closes.

Comment: http://www.blastanova.com/blog/2010/06/23/a-custom-multi-selection-spark-dropdownlist/ <= found this however I am strugling to see how to get the final array of selected checkboxes back out of it.

Comment: 1. for combobox selection. you should have a "selected" inside the object data you pass to the combobox, and assign the selected property as checkbox.selected property.     2. for the problem with autocosing when clicking a checkbox, you should be able to prevent closing of the checkbox by overriding the checkbox class.